# Получить ячейку таблицы по индексам

Tags: javascript, table

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить элемент ячейки таблицы (`HTMLTableDataCellElement`), если я знаю индексы строки и столбца, на пересечении которых находится искомая ячейка?

```js
let i = 1;
let j = 0;
let element = ???
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0,0</td>
    <td>0,1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1,0</td>
    <td>1,1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 за слово "искомая"

Answer (score 2):

```
let element = document.querySelector('table').rows[i].cells[j];
console.log(element.innerText);
```